# (Help) A quick probability question. Thanks!

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Question is:

> 3% of the population has disease X.  
> A laboratory blood test has 
>   
> (a) 96% effective at detecting disease X, given that the person
>   actually has it.  
> (b) 1% “false positive” rate. i.e, a person who
>   does not have disease X has a probability of 0.01 of obtaining a test
>   result implying they have the disease.
>
> What is the probability a person has the **disease** given that the test
>   result is **positive**?

But I'm really kinda lost about the concept of “false positive”. Is there anyone could help me out.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A "False positive" means just what it sounds like: the test gives a positive result *and* this is wrong (ie: the patient does not actually have the disease).   The *false positive rate* is the probability of a positive result for patients without the disease.

So let $D$ be the event of having the disease, and $T$ be the event of the test being positive.

> 3% of the population has disease X.

$$\mathsf P(D)=0.03$$

> A laboratory blood test has (a) 96% effective at detecting disease X, given that the person actually has it.

$$\mathsf P(T\mid D)=0.96$$

> A laboratory blood test has (b) 1% “false positive” rate. i.e, a person who does not have disease X has a probability of 0.01 of obtaining a test result implying they have the disease.

$$\mathsf P(T\mid D^\complement)=0.01$$

> What is the probability a person has the **disease** given that the test result is **positive**?

Now find $\mathsf P(D\mid T)$ using what you know of conditional probability (hint: Bayes' Rule) and the Law of Total Probability.

Comment: is my answer correct? Graham. (Sorry for directly editing your answer above, cuz I don't know how to edit LaTex in comments area.)

Comment: So, my understanding is:

(T)=P(T∣D)+P(T∣D∁)=0.97
P(T)=P(T∣D)+P(T∣D∁)=0.97
and by Bayes' Rule (D∣T)=(0.96∗0.03)/0.97P(D∣T)=(0.96∗0.03)/0.97
is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: The Law of Total Probability says: $~\mathsf P(T) ~{=~ \mathsf P(T\mid D)\,\mathsf P(D)+\mathsf P(T\mid D^\complement)\,\mathsf P(D^\complement)\\ =~  0.96\cdot 0.03+ 0.01\cdot (1-0.03)}$